# Pytest - Use caplog to verify a prompt

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, pytest

Not sure if this possible, but I want to verify that my function correctly displays a user input. I use caplog throughout my test suite to verify warning and error messages are correctly logged, but can't figure out how to utilize it to test a simple prompting of the user.

```
def test_select_org_exact_prompt(atconn, monkeypatch, caplog):
    monkeypatch.setattr("builtins.input", lambda x: "1\n")  # Select the first organization
    atconn.select_org()
    assert atconn.organization == "default"

    #Retrieve the captured logs from caplog
    
    logs = caplog.records
    print("Captured logs:\n", logs)
    # Assert that the prompt for selecting the organization was logged
    assert "Please choose an organization:" in logs
```

This is what I try, but logs is empty, presumably because it isn't a warning or error. Is this even possible using caplog or do I need to use something else?

Answer (score 0):

The `caplog` fixture only captures calls made using the stdlib `logging` module.

So things like `logger.info(..)` are captured, but `print(..)` is not. Unfortunately, `input(..)` is like `print(..)` in this regard.

However, the `capsys` fixture is exactly what you need!

https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/capture.html